# Passing functon object as filter when initializing boost log sink

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log, boost-logging

I am creating new sink like in this example:

```
void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log
    (
        keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log",
        keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024,
        keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0),
        keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%"
    );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter
    (
        logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::info
    );
}
```

I have implemented my own filter object:

```
struct MyFilter {
    ...
    bool operator()(const boost::log::attribute_value_set& attrs) const noexcept
    {
        bool result = ....
        // Do my filtering
        return result;
    }
    ...
};
```

How do I pass it as sink initialization parameter?
i.e. I want to add following parameter:

```
keywords::filter = SOMETHING(MyFilter())
```

But I so far could not figure out what that "SOMETHING" should be. Can't find any examples. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `keywords::format` is used to pass a formatter, not filter. For filters use `keywords::filter` parameter keyword.

Second, both `keywords::format` and `keywords::filter` keywords only support string arguments currently. The accepted strings are interpreted according to the syntax described [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.filter_formatter) as a formatter or filter, respectively.

If you want to set a function object as a filter, you should call `set_filter` on the created sink with your function object. `add_file_log` returns a pointer to the created sink, so you can do it like this:

```
auto sink = logging::add_file_log(...);
sink->set_filter(MyFilter());
```

The same applies to the formatter; formatting sinks provide `set_formatter` method for that.

Comment: oops, written wrong tag. should be filter of coruse, fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for explanations, Andrey!